# visibility is not working for svg g tag

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm using svg in my application and i using g tag to group the all elements. The first g tag contain more than g tag's, all g tag have their own different visibility style. If i set visibility hidden to the parent g tag it will affect the other g tag elements. I need to hide all the g tag elements by setting visibility to the parent but child elements visibility style should not change.

Here the sample svg

```
<svg height: "200" width="200">
    <g style="visibility:hidden">
        <g style="visibility:visible">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" fill="green" r="15" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the [working Sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/rnZss/)
How can set visibility to the parent g tag without changing it child elements visibility?

Comment: That's just how visibility works. What are you trying to achieve when you change the parent visibility? If the answer is nothing then just stop doing it.

Comment: Is there any reason for vote down?. can any one explain?.

Comment: I assume the downvote is because the question doesn't really make sense. You can't make a box invisible and not have the contents also be invisible.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use `opacity:0` instead of `visibility:hidden`.

Also, you should look at this example http://svg-whiz.com/svg/HideShow.svg

Comment: i need how to hide the child elements from parent style

Comment: The **only** thing that the `<g>` visibility style does is style its children. If that's not what you want then just don't do it.

Comment: @RobertLongson i need visibility property for all child elements but how to hide all child elements using its parent `<g>` element

Comment: opacity:0 to parent <g> will hide all the child of that element.

Comment: You hide all child elements by setting visibility to hidden as you are doing. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `visibility:hidden` of `<g>` should hide it's children, at least it happens for Chrome Browser. But not all renderers do it correctly (it does not happen for [SvgRen](https://github.com/igagis/svgren) for example). But there, `opacity:0` works fine. So to be saver, one should use both. Still, it depends on the renderer.

Comment: Note that another option is `display:none`, combined `style="visibility:hidden; opacity:0; display:none"`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand quite what you are after as the others have said.

I had deleted this answer, as it feels I'm missing your point, but thought it may still help http://jsfiddle.net/rnZss/5/ , it will still display the rect, but hide the circle, so I have left the answer for the moment. What else do you want to happen ?

```
<svg height:"200" width="200">
    <g style="visibility:hidden">
        <g style="visibility:hidden">
            <circle style="visibility: hidden"cx="100" cy="100" fill="green" r="15"/>
            <rect style="visibility: visible" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50"/>
        </g>
    </g>

</svg>
```